# Python: Executar classe ou elemento que esteja dentro de uma classe

Tags: python, python-3.x

existe alguma maneira de executar uma `def` que esteja dentro de uma classe ou de algum outro elemento que eu desconheço sem a necessidade de incluir o () da classe, somente com o nome? Veja no exemplo abaixo de como eu desejo que funcione, caso seja possível.

Não precisa ser necessariamente uma classe dentro de outra, pode ser outro elemento, mas que seja possível executar desta forma `crud_regionalspc.CrudTabelaDados.select()`

```
class CrudRegionalSPC:
    class CrudTabelaDados:
        def select(self):
            print("select")

        def delete(self):
            print("delete")


crud_regionalspc = CrudRegionalSPC()

# como funciona
crud_regionalspc.CrudTabelaDados().select()

# como eu gostaria que funcionasse
crud_regionalspc.CrudTabelaDados.select()
```

Comment: Poderia elaborar o por que precisa ser essa sintaxe? 
Além do que Woss e AugustoVasques comentaram sobre parecer um [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/5878), e [Flat is better than nested](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) me parece que seu cenário está querendo ter garantias que a tipagem do python poderia resolver. E, não é usual essa mistura de snake_case e camelCase na mesma instrução.

Comment: @EnriqueS.Filiage Conforme eu disse na questão, não precisava ser necessariamente uma classe dentro de outra, poderia ser outro elemento. A minha necessidade era de facilitar o processo, pois antes eu tinha uma classe com um tbl_a_select(), tbl_a_update(), tbl_a_delete() ..., tbl_b_select(),  tbl_b_update(), tbl_b_delete() ... Então pensei porque não existir algo como nome_da_datatable.nome_da_tabela.select() Entendeu? [aqui](https://ideone.com/BO36BA) fica melhor para entender, com a solução do Augusto Vasques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não sei exatamente o que quer fazer, mais vão algumas ideias:

Inicialmente pode remover o aninhamento de classes e instanciar uma propriedade:

```
class CrudTDados:
  def __init__(self, parent):
    self._parent = parent
    
  def select(self):
    print("select")

  def delete(self):
    print("delete")

 
class CrudRegionalSPC():   
  def __init__(self):
    self.CrudTabelaDados = CrudTDados(self)

    
crud_regionalspc = CrudRegionalSPC()

crud_regionalspc.CrudTabelaDados.select()
```

Pode obter o mesmo resultado usando decorators. Decorators podem ser funções ou classes que adicionam funcionalidade às funções existentes.

```
class CrudTDados:
  def __init__(self, parent):
    self._parent = parent
    
  def select(self):
    print("select")

  def delete(self):
    print("delete")

 
class CrudRegionalSPC():   
  @CrudTDados
  def CrudTabelaDados(self): pass


    
crud_regionalspc = CrudRegionalSPC()

crud_regionalspc.CrudTabelaDados.select()
```

Você também pode criar uma classe abstrata e a subclassear. Dessa forma pode intercambiar essas subclasses:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class ICrud(ABC):
  @abstractmethod
  def select(self): pass
    
  @abstractmethod
  def delete(self): pass

class CrudMudo(ICrud):
  def select(self): pass
  def delete(self): pass

class CrudTDados(ICrud):
  def select(self):
    print("select Dados")

  def delete(self):
    print("delete Dados")

class CrudTClientes(ICrud):    
  def select(self):
    print("select Clientes")

  def delete(self):
    print("delete Clientes")

 
class CrudRegionalSPC():   
  def __init__(self, crud=CrudMudo()):
    self.CrudTabelaDados = crud;

  def MudarCrud(self, crud):
    self.CrudTabelaDados = crud

    
crud_regionalspc = CrudRegionalSPC()

crud_regionalspc.CrudTabelaDados.select()

crud_regionalspc.MudarCrud(CrudTClientes())

crud_regionalspc.CrudTabelaDados.select()

crud_regionalspc.MudarCrud(CrudTDados())

crud_regionalspc.CrudTabelaDados.select()
```

Comment: Seu primeiro exemplo caiu como uma luva para o que eu preciso, segue o [ideone](https://ideone.com/BO36BA) para que entenda a minha ideia.

Answer (score 3):

Tenho que dizer que é uma estrutura bastante confusa e muito tendenciosa a ser um [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/5878).

Mas a título de conhecimento, ao definir o método como estático ele passará a atuar basicamente como uma função normal dentro da classe, então nem há a necessidade do `self` como parâmetro, visto que pertencerá à classe e não à instância.

```py
class CrudRegionalSPC:
    class CrudTabelaDados:
        @staticmethod
        def select():
            print("select")

        @staticmethod
        def delete():
            print("delete")


crud_regionalspc = CrudRegionalSPC()

# como eu gostaria que funcionasse
crud_regionalspc.CrudTabelaDados.select()  # select
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/UwWOCU)</sup>

Inclusive você não precisaria nem da instância para chamar a função desejada:

```
CrudRegionalSPC.CrudTabelaDados.select()
```

Pois assim as classes estariam atuando basicamente como *namespaces*.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, conforme eu queria, mas minha necessidade ainda sim precisa do self. Mas já me deu um parâmetro do que posso fazer.
A questão do problema é que eu tenho que sempre criar uma função tabela_select, tabela_update, tabela_delete e assim por diante para outras.
Estava pensando em montar algo que ficasse mais simples exemplo Datatable.Tabela.select()
Desde já muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Então realmente é um problema XY e essa não é a forma ideal de resolver o seu problema.

Comment: [Flat is better than nested.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)